# Overlay specification with beamer and '\colorbox'

Tags: beamer, overlays, colorbox

I use `\colorbox` in my slides to highlight part of the text (as if it was highlighted with a marker).  The command also accepts beamer overlay specifications (e.g. `\colorbox<1>{yellow}{Text}`).  However, strangely enough on the slides that does not match the overlay specification the text is replaced by a purely black rectangle.  More specifically, `colorbox<1>{yellow}{Text}` produces "Text" with yellow background on slide 1 and on the following slides produces a black rectangle (as if it was generated by `\colorbox{black}{Text}`).  Any ideas on why this is happening and how can be fixed?

Many thanks,

---

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\centering
\colorbox<1>{yellow}{Text}

\onslide<2->{Some other text}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And here are the first and second slides resulted from the above example:
[image: Slide 1]
[image: Slide 2]

Comment: Could you show a Minimum working (or not) example? From `\documentclass` to `\end{document`.

Comment: @Ignasi Done :-)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could redefine `\colorbox`:

```
\renewcommand<>\colorbox[2]{\only#3{\beameroriginal\colorbox{#1}{#2}}}
```

But maybe it is better to define a new command:

```
\newcommand<>\hlbox[2]{\only#3{\colorbox{#1}{#2}}}
```

Example

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand<>\hlbox[2]{\only#3{\colorbox{#1}{#2}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\centering
\hlbox<1>{yellow}{Text}
\par
Text
\par
\onslide<1-2>{Some other text}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you want something like

[image]

you could use

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\newcommand<>\highlightbox[2]{%
  \alt#3{\makebox[\dimexpr\width-2\fboxsep]{\colorbox{#1}{#2}}}{#2}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Some Fancy Title}
\centering
Text \highlightbox<2>{yellow}{Text} Text
\par
Text Text Text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  In fact I ended up with writing something similar to your second proposition manually everywhere.  Your idea of defining a new command is much more efficient.

Comment: P.S.  I guess the order of `\makebox` and `\colorbox` should be reversed in your version of `\highlightbox`.  Otherwise, the highlight gets extended to adjacent characters if for example you only highlight a letter in a word.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your code, the `colorbox` is set to yellow only on frame 1, but to black (maybe the standard value?) on all other frames. Including an extra `only` around the `colorbox` made sure that it's only displayed on frame 1.

I tried removing the overlay specification (`<1>`) from the `colorbox`, since it seemed redundant. The code compiles, but the text is moved towards the left...

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \centering
    \only<1>{\colorbox<1>{yellow}{Text}}
    \onslide<2->{Some other text}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```